# Benefits of knowing theory

Tags: undergraduate-education, secondary-education, examples, intuition

I've got an issue: from time to time I have to teach some math to people who either avoided it, or got through by only knowing a few working algorithms. The only thing that unites all those people: they are sure that math is extremely boring and there's no sense an learning anything except for how to solve the tasks they're given.

I want to be sure that my lessons not only provide primitive formulas or concepts, but motivate students for learning more about the topic, thus I need to show how all that 'pointless knowledge' may turn out to be not so pointless.

Doing that I usually find myself troubled by lacking proper examples of why a sophisticated theory can actually turn out to be benificial for anyone who isn't pursuing a career of a scholar, programmer, nuclear physicist etc.

As for now I'm limited to usual stuff:

1) Showing how some analysis tricks can make computations easier (L'Hopital's rule and all that) or even possible (in case our only option for a function is approximating it with a series)

2) Show how grasping visual ideas can make it much easier to use all monstrous formulas — case of basic linear algebra (determinants, linear transformations, matrix multiplication etc.)

3) Explaining how treating multiplication as area can allow to derive all neede polynomial formulas (including solving quadratics) without knowing anything else.

4) Refering to how going beyond the scope of a usual math course can make life easier while dealing with polynomials — e.g. knowing the Fundamental theorem and rules of polynomial division, rational roots test etc.

In a desperate search of inspiration I've watched some video courses (the best one yet is Revisiting Calculus by Herb Gross) as well as popular math youtubbers (Numberphile, Mathologer, 3Blue1Brown and others), but still feel like I can use a lot of help from people of the Math community who have way more experience in the field.

I don't teach anything fancy: basic elementary math, some trigonometry, calculus, and basic linear algebra.

Thanks kindly for your insights and suggestions.

Comment: My sense is that this question is overly broad, as the kind of example you need will necessarily vary from topic to topic. However in general I think it is always possibly to justify the position that "remembering stuff" is almost always less reliable than "understanding stuff". Memories fail; formulas and mnemonics are easily mis-remembered when we need them. Once we understand something, on the other hand, it tends to stay understood.

Comment: @mweiss thanks, you got my idea exactly — understanding demands less memory a proves to be more sustainable in the long term.

However, I'm kinda lost in terms of advices. For example, should I tell them to study some group theory, will it help them in their tasks?

Any use in studying all the rigorous theorems of classical analysis (with all the points and segments)?

Perhaps suggesting basic stuff from topology could come in handy? Will simmetry and transofrmation groups somehow be useful in working with typical figures in ${\mathbb R}^2$ and ${\mathbb R}^3$?

Comment: @mweiss Unfortunately (or fortunately) I don't have any formal education in math and people I know are very advanced mathematicians who almost don't deal with 'practical issues', so I have no one to turn to.

Comment: I think it depends on what they need to learn. I doubt very much there is a one-size-fits-all prescription that will work (see my initial comment about this question being overly broad). You began your post by saying "from time to time I have to teach some math to people" -- perhaps if you unpack what you mean by "some math" we can give you more targeted advice.

Comment: @mweiss you're right, that's why I'm not looking for prescriptions but rather for some valuable shorcuts and theory applications. I've specified that I teach basic school stuff: calculus, polynomial eqautions, trigonometry, simple linear algebra (including trivial linear optimization cases) and so on.

Comment: Those all feel very different to me, each calling for its own network of theoretical ideas.

Comment: Are you talking about people who are resistant to theory of all kinds, or only to theory in mathematics?  If it's the latter, you can leverage their appreciation of theory in some other field.  If it's the former, you need to be working with the people who are teaching the students in other subjects.  I don't think it's particularly helpful to see this as an issue isolated to mathematics.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I'm talking about people who do not excel at science and don't care about any theory unless it's explicitly show to them as a viable shortcut for solving practical tasks easier and faster. The only way their views can be altered (to my mind) is by providing enough examples showing that learning a bit of theory (i.e. something about group theory) actually allows them to understand some other stuff more deeply and efficiently.

Comment: @user2057368 - there is theory in the humanities also - in fact in every field of academic study.  What kinds of theory are they getting in their other studies?  Do they care about that either?  If they don't care about ideas and thinking at all, why are they in school?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo from what I've observed about 90% of people I deal with aren't interested in their subjects at all, they are just there to get their diplomas (either because they think it will help them with jobs or because their parents want them to do so). So they either will look for a way to completely avoid doing something, or do that in the most simple way possible. That's where I want to fit in and demonstrate that actually understanding some field is better than memorizing solving algorithms.

Comment: I do feel this question is too broad (voting to close; no answers after a bout a week; voting to close). Perhaps if you searched/asked questions about one particular subject at a time?

Comment: The only way is to relate it to something they're interested in. Often that will feed back. Art, music, whatever. There's use for math in all that stuff. It's hard to tell from your post whether you had a curriculum to stick to or not. But personally I think getting them to do something related to their interest then feeding it back is a much better approach than just telling them how useful math is for math.

Answer (score 1):

> I ... find myself troubled by lacking proper examples of why a sophisticated theory can actually turn out to be beneficial ...

I agree this is troubling. "I feel your pain," as the saying goes.
I would like to suggest that 
computer graphics can serve as a source for a subset of the examples you seek: to motivate polynomials, and motivate finding roots of polynomials.

Every time you print text in a particular font (e.g., [Postscript Type-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Type_1)) on a laser printer you are using
cubic polynomials. That every printer in the world is using cubic polynomials every day can
be a compelling story.

Finding roots of such polynomials is a common
need in computer graphics, e.g., to compute the highlights on a shiny
3D surface, like an apple.
The challenge is to intersect a light-ray with a cubic surface patch.
Search for ray-tracing Bézier, or B-spline, or NURBS surfaces to see more examples of this calculation.

---

[image]

          

<sup>(Image from [JTrace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqgmLmIgLSo).)</sup>

---